# How to use Single Live Event to open a dialog fragment with data from Room?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm doing an expenses apps, where I have a room database to save expenses in one table and the items in another table.
What I'm trying to do is get the items by the expense id, and display those elements in a dialog fragment. I use Live data to do the query, but every time I add a new expense and return to the fragment those dialog fragment are open again. As far as I understand this is because Livedata, and to prevent this I have to use SingleLiveEvent, but I can't figure out how to correctly implement it.

I'm still new in android development so I'll be glad if anyone can tell me about some resouces where I can learn more about this, or what I can improve in my code.

This is my ItemsDao

```
interface ItemsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Items)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE expenseId = :id")
    fun getItemByID(id: Long): LiveData<List<Items>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items_table")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Items>>

    @Update
    suspend fun updateItems(item: Items)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteItem(item: ArrayList<Items>)
}
```

My repository

```
class ExpensesRepository(private val expensesDao: ExpensesDao, private val itemsDao: ItemsDao) {
    // Room executes all queries on a separate thread.
    // Observed Flow will notify the observer when the data has changed.
    val allExpenses: Flow<List<Expenses>> = expensesDao.getAllExpenses()

    val allItems: Flow<List<Items>> = itemsDao.getAllItems()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteExpense(expense: Expenses) {
        return expensesDao.deleteExpense(expense)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteItem(items: ArrayList<Items>) {
        return itemsDao.deleteItem(items)
    }

    // By default Room runs suspend queries off the main thread, therefore, we don't need to
    // implement anything else to ensure we're not doing long running database work
    // off the main thread.
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(expense: Expenses): Long {
        return expensesDao.insert(expense)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insertExpenseAndItem(expense: Expenses, items: List<Items>){

        val id = expensesDao.insert(expense)
        for (item: Items in items){
            item.expenseId = id
            Log.d("repository", "The id to insert ${item.id}")
            Log.d("repository", "The item to insert $item")
            itemsDao.insert(item)
        }

    }
    suspend fun updateExpenseAndItems(expense: Expenses, items: List<Items>){
        /*expensesDao.updateExpense(expense.concept, expense.date, expense.total, expense.id)*/
        expensesDao.updateExpense(expense)
        Log.d("upsert", items.toString())
        for (item in items){
            if (item.id != 0L) itemsDao.updateItems(item)
            else {
                item.expenseId = expense.id
                itemsDao.insert(item)
            }
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun getItemById(id: Long): LiveData<List<Items>> {
        return itemsDao.getItemByID(id)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun getExpensesByDate(desiredDate: String): LiveData<List<Expenses>> {
        return expensesDao.getExpensesByDate(desiredDate)
    }

}
```

My View Model

```
class ExpenseViewModel(private val repository: ExpensesRepository): ViewModel() {
  val allExpenses: LiveData<List<Expenses>> = repository.allExpenses.asLiveData()

  val itemList: SingleLiveEvent<List<Items>> = SingleLiveEvent()

  fun getExpensesByDate(desiredDate: String): LiveData<List<Expenses>> {
    return repository.getExpensesByDate(desiredDate)
  }

  // Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
  fun insert(expense: Expenses, item: List<Items>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insertExpenseAndItem(expense, item)
  }

  fun getItemById(id: Long): LiveData<List<Items>> {
    return repository.getItemById(id)
  }

  fun updateExpenseAndItems(expense: Expenses, item: List<Items>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.updateExpenseAndItems(expense, item)
  }

  fun deleteExpense(expense: Expenses) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      repository.deleteExpense(expense)
    }
  }

  fun deleteItems(items: ArrayList<Items>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      repository.deleteItem(items)
    }
  }
}

class ExpenseViewModelFactory(private val repository: ExpensesRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory{
  override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ExpenseViewModel::class.java)){
      @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
      return ExpenseViewModel(repository) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view model class")
  }
}
```

Comment: SingleLiveEvent has always been an anti-pattern, so you probably actually just wanted to expose `allExpenses` then open the dialog from the fragment

Comment: I'm still new to this, is it a bad practice have more than one view model? As far as I understand I must have only one view model in the main activity.

Comment: No, you can have multiple of them, but the issue here is trying to use `SingleLiveEvent` for `itemList`